# Azure_rm.py: skipping: no hosts matched

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**Environment:**

```
 Ansible version: 2.4
    Component name: azure_rm
    Cloud: Azure
    Terraform:0.11.1
    Provider: azure_rm v0.3.3
```

Trying to get ansible work with **azure_rm.py** and for some reason it is not processing tags I supplied with terraform.

I have tag created in my terraform file like this:

```
tags {
  environment = "${var.environment_tag}"
   role = "${var.zookeeper_role_tag}"
}
```

Where in **variables.tf** I have the following:

```
variable "zookeeper_role_tag" {
   description = "ZooKeeper Role Tag"
   default = "zookeepernodes"
}
```

Now, in my **azure_rm.ini**, I have the following entries:

```
[azure]
# Control which resource groups are included. By default all resources groups are included.
# Set resource_groups to a comma separated list of resource groups names.
resource_groups=rgTest

# Control which tags are included. Set tags to a comma separated list of keys or key:value pairs
#tags=zookeeper_role_tag:zookeepernodes,broker_role_tag:kafkanodes
tags=zookeepernodes,kafkanodes

# Control which locations are included. Set locations to a comma separated list (e.g. eastus,eastus2,westus)
locations=eastus

# Include powerstate. If you don't need powerstate information, turning it off improves runtime performance.
include_powerstate=yes

# Control grouping with the following boolean flags. Valid values: yes, no, true, false, True, False, 0, 1.
group_by_resource_group=yes
group_by_location=yes
group_by_security_group=yes
group_by_tag=yes
```

I execute the script using terraform's **remote-exec**:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = 
    "ansible-playbook -i ~/ansible/contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py ~/${var.ansible_file}/ansible_kafka.yml -e 'ansible_user=ansible01 ansible_group=ansgroup kafka_user=kafkauser kafka_group=kafkagroup zookeeper_user=kafkauser zookeeper_group=kafkagroup"
      ]
  }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): PLAY [zookeepernodes:kafkanodes] 
***********************************************
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): skipping: no hosts matched

azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): PLAY [zookeepernodes] 
**********************************************************
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): skipping: no hosts matched

azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): PLAY [kafkanodes] 
**************************************************************
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): skipping: no hosts matched

azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[0] (remote-exec): PLAY [all]      
*********************************************************************
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion.0: Still creating... (4m50s elapsed)
```

Shown above, **azure_rm.py** is not picking up tagged nodes (`zookeepernodes, kafkanodes`).

Any pointers what is it I am doing wrong ? Thanks again!!

Comment: "*Shown above, azure_rm.py is not picking*" -- above I see everything except for the output of `~/ansible/contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @techraf. I am using vanilla contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py but overriding variables with azure_rm.ini. So in a way, I am not changing azure_rm.py from the original image. Don't know if it is right or wrong, but this the idea I've got from reading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "tags=zookeepernodes,kafkanodes" in azure_rm.ini file write:

```
tags=role:zookeepernodes
```

you could also include kafkanodes nodes by doing this:

```
tags=role:zookeepernodes,role:kafkanodes
```

It's "key:value". In your case role is a key and zookeepernodes is a value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @GregS. Tried with and with suggested recommendation:

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @GregS. Tried with and with suggested recommendation with key/value in azure_rm.ini. However, still got the following:  "azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[1] (remote-exec):  [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: zookeepernodes
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[1] (remote-exec):
azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion[1] (remote-exec):  [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: kafkanodes"